# Sun One Web Server 6.1 and Tomahawk

Tags: jsf, deployment, tomahawk, sunone

Do anyone know which version of tomahawk is suitable to use with Sun One Webserver 6.1?

Thanks in advance,
Alejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a requirements table for JSF:

```
JSF       | 1.0   | 1.1   | 1.2 (JEE5) | 2.0
---------------------------------------------
Java      | 1.3   | 1.3   | 5          | *
JSP       | 1.2   | 1.2   | 2.1        | *
Servlet   | 2.3   | 2.3   | 2.5        | *
JavaBeans | 1.0.1 | 1.0.1 | 1.0.1      | *
JSTL      | 1.0   | 1.0   | 1.2        | *

*JSF 2.0 Public Review Draft requires JEE5
```

The Sun ONE Web Server doc says this:

> Sun ONE Web Server 6.1 supports the
>   Java Servlet 2.3 specification,
>   including web application and WAR file
>   (Web ARchive file) support, and the
>   JavaServer Pages (JSP) 1.2
>   specification.

So, I'd use the [compatibility matrix](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/CompatibilityMatrix) to check for likely candidates.